# How can I add custom stickers to Adobe Creative SDK Image Editor

Tags: adobecreativesdk

I've integrated Adobe Creative SDK into my App. The Image Editor has a default set of stickers on the Android platform. On the iOS, in addition to the default stickers, there is also a "supply" button which lets the user pick other sticker packs. How can this functionality be enabled in the Android version of the SDK?